# How to use QueryComponent with pollInterval and local state changes

Tags: react-apollo, apollo-client

i'm writing a small search app which starts a search over a RESTapi. Until the search is finished the api respond with a 260 status code or a 250 if the search is finished.
For this purpose i've written a component with a Query component which polls the RESTapi:

```
import React from 'react';
import gql from "graphql-tag";
import { Query } from "react-apollo";

export const GET_SEARCH_RESULTS = gql`
  query GetSearchResults($sid: String!) {
      getSearchResults(sid: $sid) {
          status,
          clusteredOffers { 
              id,
              bookingId,
              totalPrice
          }
      }
  }
`;

export default class extends React.PureComponent {
  client = null;

  updateStatus = (data) => {
    this.client.writeData({ data: { currentSearch: { status: 
data.getSearchResults.status, __typename: 'CurrentSearch' }} })
  };

  render() {
    const { sid } = this.props;

    return (
      <Query
        query={GET_SEARCH_RESULTS}
        variables={{ sid }}
        pollInterval={500}
        onCompleted={this.updateStatus}
      >
        {({ loading, error, data, stopPolling, client }) => {
          this.client = client;

          if (loading) return 'Loading...';
          if (error) return `Error! ${error.message}`;

          if(data.getSearchResults.status && 
data.getSearchResults.status !== "260") stopPolling();

          return (
            <div>
              {data.getSearchResults.clusteredOffers.map(offer => (
                  <div key={offer.id} >
                  <div>{offer.id}</div>
                  <div>{offer.bookingId}</div>
                  <div>{offer.totalPrice}</div>
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          )
        }}
      </Query>
    )
  }
}
```

In a parent component i also need the status of the current search. So i've added a clientState to my ApolloClient to write the remote data to the client cache:

```
import ApolloClient from "apollo-boost";
import Search from './components/Search';

const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: "http://localhost:4000/graphql",
  clientState: {
    defaults: {
      currentSearch: {
        __typename: 'CurrentSearch',
        status: "0"
      }
    },
  }
});

....
const GET_CURRENT_SEARCH_STATE = gql`
    {
    currentSearch @client {
      status
    }
  }
`;
```

As u can see i'm using onCompleted inside my polling query component to write the current status to the local cache.

Does it make sense or should i read the status from the cached remote data? If so, how i get the cached remote data?

thank you!